# AVCaptureSession and white screen

Tags: ios11, swift4, avcapturesession

My layout has two views See the pic:
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gzEY.jpg)

View1 is fullscreen, view2 framed in red bounds is a sublayer of view1. Both views are transparent and do nothing yet but camera broadcast. The code is:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class CameraView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
        }
    }

    override var layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        get {
            return super.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        }
    }
}

class SceneViewController: ARSceneViewController, 
AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var testFrameView: UIView?
    var cameraView: CameraView!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    cameraView = CameraView()
    testFrameView = cameraView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let testFrameView = testFrameView {
        testFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        testFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        testFrameView.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        view.addSubview(testFrameView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: testFrameView)
        }
    }    
}
```

testFrameView is my view2. Now I want my testFrameView to capture something. That's why class CameraView was created. I add input like this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class CameraView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
        }
    }

    override var layer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        get {
            return super.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        }
    }
}

class SceneViewController: ARSceneViewController, 
AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var testFrameView: UIView?
    var cameraView: CameraView!

    /////////////////   NEW   /////////////////
    let session = AVCaptureSession()    
    let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: AVCaptureSession.self.description(), attributes: [], target: nil) 
    /////////////////   NEW   /////////////////   

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    cameraView = CameraView()
    testFrameView = cameraView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let testFrameView = testFrameView {
        testFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        testFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        testFrameView.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        view.addSubview(testFrameView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: testFrameView)
        }
    }   

    /////////////////   NEW   /////////////////
    session.beginConfiguration()

    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

    if (videoDevice != nil) {
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!)

        if (videoDeviceInput != nil) {
            if (session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput!)) {
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput!)
            }
        }
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()

    cameraView.layer.session = session 
    /////////////////   NEW   /////////////////
}
```

Now view2 (aka testFrameView or CameraView) is ok, but view1 gets blocked with white screen like this:
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjFJt.jpg)

The question is: why view1 gets blocked when I run capture session using view2. How to avoid it?